# LVM2 can not wake up suspended logical volume

Tags: lvm

Read my story below.

I'm using LVM2 with following information:

Scan for VG:

```
# vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  unix   1   1   0 wz--n- 115.00g 45.00g
```

Scan for LV

```
# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr   LSize  Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  work unix -wi-s- 70.00g
```

Attempt to activate VG, LV

```
# vgchange -ay
  device-mapper: resume ioctl failed: Invalid argument
  Unable to resume unix-work (254:1)
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "unix" now active
```

Check LV activated or not

```
# lvdisplay 
  /dev/mapper/unix-work: open failed: No such file or directory
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/unix/work
  VG Name                unix
  LV UUID                HzzTTr-rX2d-w1dP-NEQL-QksJ-rmHW-jMTxO7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                70.00 GiB
  Current LE             17920
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Because of last command end with error: "/dev/mapper/unix-work: open failed: No such file or directory"
Then I have to run vgmknodes to manual create /dev/ nodes as below

```
# vgmknodes 
  The link /dev/unix/work should had been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.
```

Now it look like better with status "suspended"

```
# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/unix/work
  VG Name                unix
  LV UUID                HzzTTr-rX2d-w1dP-NEQL-QksJ-rmHW-jMTxO7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              suspended
  # open                 0
  LV Size                70.00 GiB
  Current LE             17920
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1
```

Attempt to mount LV:

```
# mount /dev/unix/work /mnt/
mount: /dev/mapper/unix-work already mounted or /mnt/ busy
```

Message from dmesg:

```
[ 1527.566964] device-mapper: table: 254:1: sda3 too small for target: start=94372224, len=136306688, dev_size=224606491
```

So, my question is: how can I wake up LV to mount it or use `dd` command to get data from LVM partition?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: 1. try update the follwing packges `kernel` , `device-mapper`, `lvm2` .
 2. deactivate with `vgchange -an` ,  then activate with  `vgchange -ay`.

Comment: Already read on LVM FAQ but not tried yet, I'm using live cd of Arch Bang so can not make a kernel update. I think it is not related to kernel since I use live cd before & after this problem happen. 
FYI: `uname -a`
`Linux archbang 3.0-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 19 10:27:51 CEST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`

Comment: The output from `pvdisplay` and `fdisk -lu /dev/sda` would be helpful.  This part makes it sound like your partition holding the PV has shrunk, which is a big problem: sda3 too small for target: start=94372224, len=136306688, dev_size=224606491

Comment: @Hannan: I have installed Arch Linux to another partition and using latest linux kernel: `Linux hydrogen 3.1.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 22 09:17:56 CET 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux`
but still get the same result as last time I did. 

@psusi: My hdd is in GPT, so fdisk will not work. I use gdisk (AKA gpt fdisk).

Comment: @UocNguyen, then whatever the equivalent for gfdisk is.  The point is to verify that the partition is as large as LVM expects it to be.

Comment: @psusi: the size of PV even larger then VG, I tried to extend it to resolve 'too small for target' problem but no luck.  
I tried to use `dd` to dump that partition but failed because of /dev/mapper/unix-work have 0 bytes of size :(   
Any suggest?

Comment: @UocNguyen, only what I already asked for.  You need to figure out why LVM is trying to use more space than exists on that partition.

Comment: @psusi: forgot to mention that I was have problem with it in the past, I used ArchBang Live CD to boot up and manipulate data from LVM, after I remove 2 LV from VG `unix`, create, delete some partition. After that I invoke `sync`, `partprobe` but they all freeze, later I was reboot my machine then problem with LVM come.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to this post https://superuser.com/questions/1061454/how-to-resize-back-a-logical-volumen-lvm/1061548

As suggested by the psusi comment, the PV on /dev/sda3 seems to be smaller than the VG size (perhaps a `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize somesizeG` was done at a time)

2 solutions :
   - extend the /dev/sda3
   - reduce the unix-work LV

But need the `pvdisplay and /dev/sda3` infos